# select keeps waiting indefinitely

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select

I'm getting a strange result while experimenting with select().

```
fd_set tempset,set; //set of descriptors

FD_ZERO(&set); //initialize descriptor set to NULL

FD_SET(serversock,&set); //add server's socket to descriptor set 'set'

timeout.tv_sec=2;
timeout.tv_usec=0;

while(1){

tempset=set;
timeout.tv_sec=2;
timeout.tv_usec=0;

printf("%s","Waiting on select\n");

int ret=select(FD_SETSIZE,&tempset,NULL,NULL,&timeout);

if(ret==0) printf("timeout ");

else if(ret==-1){
    printf("Error occured\n");
    exit(0);
}

else if(ret>0){ //socket ready for reading

    for(i=0;i<FD_SETSIZE;i++){

    if(FD_ISSET(i,&tempset)){ //check if it's serversock

        if(i==serversock){
              //accept connection and read/write
              printf("Client connected\n");

    }//i==serversock close

    }
}//for ends 
}
```

When i remove the the line printf("%s","Waiting on select\n"); select keeps waiting indefinitely. However, when i reinsert the line, everything works as expected (tested with a client connection)

Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to re-initialize the file descriptor set prior to each call to select in this loop.

Comment: You might have a stdio buffering effect. Try adding a newline to your "timeout " message, i.e. `printf("timeout \n");` and see if that changes what you observe. I'll bet your `select()` is actually timing out every 2 seconds but you can't see it without the top `printf` flushing the `stdout` line buffer.

Comment: Yes, adding a new line after timeout does the trick. Thanks!
But why does stdout need to be flushed in order for select to work?

Answer (score 3):

You are misususing `FD_SETSIZE`, which you should not be using directly at all.  You are only putting one socket into the `fd_set`, so there is no need to even loop through it at all (but if you did need to, use the `fd_set.fd_count` member instead).

Try this:

```
fd_set set;
timeval timeout;

while(1){ 
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(serversock, &set);

    timeout.tv_sec = 2; 
    timeout.tv_usec = 0; 

    printf("%s","Waiting on select\n"); 

    int ret = select(serversock+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout); 

    if (ret==0){
        printf("timeout "); 
    }

    else if (ret==-1){ 
        printf("Error occured\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 

    else if (ret>0){ //socket ready for reading 
        ... = accept(serversock, ...);
        printf("Client connected\n"); 
    }
}
```

Or:

```
fd_set set;
timeval timeout;
int max_fd = 0;

while(1){ 
    FD_ZERO(&set);

    FD_SET(serversock, &set);
    max_fd = serversock;

    // FD_SET() other sockets and updating max_fd as needed...

    timeout.tv_sec = 2; 
    timeout.tv_usec = 0; 

    printf("%s","Waiting on select\n"); 

    int ret = select(max_fd+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout); 

    if (ret==0){
        printf("timeout "); 
    }

    else if (ret==-1){ 
        printf("Error occured\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 

    else if (ret>0){ //socket(s) ready for reading 
        for (u_int i = 0; i < set.fd_count; ++i){
            ... = accept(set.fd_array[i], ...);
            printf("Client connected\n"); 
        }
    }
}
```